# Filtering Array entries ElasticSearch

Tags: elasticsearch

So I have an index in my Elasticsearch cluster.

Each document has a nested field `Reviews` which is an array of different reviews. Each entry of `Reviews` array is a JSON and has a field `Content` containing the actual content of the review.

Now for a given document, I want only that reviews from `Reviews` array which contain a particular keyword (like `happy`) in their `Content`. I am not able to figure out the query to do this. Can anybody please tell me how to do the above query.

Answer (score 0):

You need `inner_hits` for this kind of requirement. Documentation [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/5.4/search-request-inner-hits.html#nested-inner-hits).

In the result of the query below you need to look after the `inner_hits` section of each document. That will show you only those Contents that matched.

How to use it:

```
DELETE test
PUT test
{
  "mappings": {
    "test": {
      "properties": {
        "Reviews": {
          "type": "nested",
          "properties": {
            "Content": {
              "type": "string"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
POST /test/test/1
{
  "Reviews": [
    {
      "Content": "happy dog"
    },
    {
      "Content": "testing testing"
    }
  ]
}
POST /test/test/2
{
  "Reviews": [
    {
      "Content": "happy cat, happy owner"
    },
    {
      "Content": "whatever"
    },
    {
      "Content": "another happy customer"
    }
  ]
}

GET /test/_search
{
  "_source": false, 
  "query": {
    "nested": {
      "path": "Reviews",
      "query": {
        "match": {
          "Reviews.Content": "happy"
        }
      },
      "inner_hits" : {}
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Did my answer help you in any way?